# Move Huge files from one server to another via SSH

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, wget

I have been trying to move huge files from one server to another one via ssh using wget and scp commands but the tar.gz file get corrupted and wont extract. The files is over 30 to 50GBs. **Is there any other better way to move .tar.gz files?**

Comment: how far apart are the servers?

Comment: one is in Texas and another one in California

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use `rsync` which will automatically resume if you need to restart it and will calculate checksums on your file as part of its transfer process.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh you may use a console FTP client to send it to the server.

The FTP protocol is made for this, so the transfert should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SFTP client able to handle broken connections and reconnect, for instance [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/).

In order to recover a corrupted transfer, use `rsync`. It will efficiently compare the remote and local files and transfer only the parts that differ.